# how to merge two _io.TextIOWrapper files?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I'm making a password generator project in **python 3.8**. It's basically about storing passwords in a plain text file and encrypt it using GPG (I'm using Linux). The program checks whether there is an encrypted file or not (This happens in the `try` block). If so, the encrypted file gets decrypted, then added to the plain text file and finally gets encrypted again. Then, the plain text file gets deleted. The question is how to **merge** the **encrypted** file and the **plain text** one ? Here is the code:

```
with open("test.txt","a+") as passwords_file:
        passwords_file.write(account_name_pass + "\n")
        try:
            with open("test.txt.gpg",'r') as decrypted_file:
                subprocess.run('gpg -o test.txt --decrypt test.txt.gpg', shell=True)
                
                # How to merge 2 _io.textIOwrapper files here?
                result = passwords_file.write(decrypted_file)
                print(result)
        except FileNotFoundError:
                subprocess.run('gpg -o test.txt.gpg -e -r michelojordan@protonmail.com test.txt', shell=True)
os.remove("test.txt")
```

I used the `write( )` function but i got this error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Neither `append( )` seems to work:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I've been searching for so long now. Help will be REALLY appreciated.

Comment: `passwords_file.write(decrypted_file.read())` ?

Comment: I tried that too but i get the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 0: invalid start byte